# where to store large data instead of cookies

Tags: javascript, django, indexeddb, web-sql

I am developing an application(Django 1.11.10) in which there is a module called RoleBasedAccessControl so I after user login I have soo much data(permission data in JSON format) from the database(MySQL) which defines different type of permission on different resource types.

I searched on the internet and got several options like "client-side storage", "indexedDb" etc.. which can store large data to client side but I am not sure that I can access my permission data at server whenever required(as I can do with cookies using getCookies but cookies have a limit of 4 kb)

So my issue is where to manage that permission JSON data so both server and client can access to check whether following permission is valid or not if the user was trying to perform any action and this data can get bigger is size as creating more resources by the user.

Otherwise, I need to hit DB request from both client(via ajax) and server 
to check the particular permission before the user can perform any action.

Please suggest me a way to manage my permission JSON data where should store it.

Comment: *" i am not sure that i can access my permission data at server"* wait, what? Are you trusting permission data from the client? Or did I misunderstand this sentence?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca you understood it correctly, and sorry if i am making a big security issue here by storing permission data locally, please suggest me what should i do if  user clicks on a resource and i need to check the permission first.. if data is locally available i can check very fastly, otherwise i need to ajax on db.

Comment: Depends on your threat model. I don't know enough about your application to make a sensible suggestion. Just, think about it

Comment: You can save some kind of user identifier in a cookie and then retrieve the larger data with that id on demand from something like Redis (one DB hit, then cached). Depends on the app and the requirements, but this is an option you can consider,

Answer (score 1):

You Can use client Storage 
localStorage.setItem('name','Chris');
var myName = localStorage.getItem('name');
Here is reference Site

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage